# Using GREP to find a list of genes (around 200) in a whole exome tab delimited text file

Tags: linux, ubuntu, grep

I would like to extract all rows containing genes of interest from a very large exome file (txt tab-delimited).

It is not practical to GREP them individually so I thought I would put them in a text file as a list and use the following command.

```
grep -E Gene_list.txt Sample1_GREP.txt > Output.txt
```

This is taking ages to iterate and I did try other alternatives but came nowhere near to finding a solution.

Comment: Grep probably isn't the best tool for the job.   I would suggest creating a database with appropriate indexes, and parse the data into the db, after which you can search on pre-indexed data.  That way you only pay the overhead of searching the data once, upon inserting the data.

Answer (score 0):

200 patterns is not large for grep by any means. Try GNU grep (sometimes `ggrep`), which is faster than BSD grep. Also, use `tr` to translate `Gene_list.txt` tab delimiters to newlines:

```
tr '\t' '\n' < Gene_list.txt | ggrep -F -f - Sample1_GREP.txt > Output.txt
```